# Void Update not updating enough fast

Tags: android, function, unity-game-engine

I'm just trying to create a camera for an android game with which you can zoom and move on the x axis and I want to make a limit for this camera. For example, I want that the camera stop zooming when the orthographicSize is bigger than my variable max_zoom or smaller than my variable min_zoom.

The problem is that if the user zooms very fast, the update function doesn't update enough fast and for example, the orthographicSize is equals to 0.995 even if my min_zoom variable is equals to 1. Here is my condition :

```
if(GetComponent<Camera> ().orthographicSize > min_zoom && GetComponent<Camera> ().orthographicSize < max_zoom) {
    // .. change the orthographic size based on the change in distance between the touches.
    GetComponent<Camera> ().orthographicSize += deltaMagnitudeDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;

    // Make sure the orthographic size never drops below zero.
    GetComponent<Camera> ().orthographicSize = Mathf.Max(GetComponent<Camera> ().orthographicSize, 0.1f);

}
```

So the problem is that the user can't zoom out.

Comment: Why do you keep making calls to `GetComponent<Camera> ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i finally found the solution for the zoom. I simply removed the condition, and at the end of my script, i used Mathf.clamp to set the orthographicSize between my min_zoom and max_zoom. The last problem i have but it's not about the zoom, is that i can't make a fix limit at the right and at the left because when you zoom, the coordonates of the limit changes, but that's the subject of another topic. Thank you for your answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `GetComponent<Camera>()` for each function, you can call in start it is enough.

```
    Camera cam; 

    void Start () 
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if( cam.orthographicSize > min_zoom && cam.orthographicSize < max_zoom) 
        {
            cam.orthographicSize += deltaMagnitudeDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;

            cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Max(cam.orthographicSize, 0.1f);

        }
    }
```

Comment: All you have done is made the code easier to read, how does it address _"The problem is that if the user zooms very fast, the update function doesn't update enough fast"_

Comment: I wanted to help with example, if I wrote this on comment it was hard to understand. No problem, I will delete the answer after reading.

Comment: Exactly, i tried this and the performances were a bit better but it didn't changed anything to the problem. I just found a temporary solution, i just made a condition that is called when the zoom is smaller than my variable min_zoom then i set the orthographicSize to the minzoom, and the same for the max zoom but it's really horrible because when you zoom very fast, it zoom out instantly. Still searching a soluion, thank you anyway for your answer.